# python command line error,am new to using python on command prompt.Hence some one clarify what is wrong in this?

Tags: python, command, line

[image]

am new to using python on command prompt.Hence some one clarify what is wrong in this?

Comment: Why the close votes? This is a good question about how the python shell works.

Comment: The "..." are a visual queue that you are still in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press enter twice after the line `print("big")`.

In general when using the interactive python shell, you press enter twice to exit from a code block (e.g. `for` loop or `if`). This will then execute that block and `>>>` will be shown on the left hand side of your command line. You can then enter further commands to be executed.

In your case, your output should then be:

```
>>> x = 11
>>> if x > 10:
...     print("big")
... 
big
>>> print("done")
done
```